# Magento 2 Products Missing from Category Pages after Magento 2.4.5 Update

Tags: php, elasticsearch, magento2, magento2.4

After updating to Magento 2.4.5 product category pages no longer show products. However, the filters on the left side of the page indicate that products should be visible for instance:

[image: Magento 2 products missing]

I've tried the following to fix the issue to no avail:

- Disabled all custom plugins
- Reverted to the default Luna theme
- Reindex
- Clear cache
- Restarted Elasticsearch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long search I was able to find this issue and work-around for this problem. It seems to be an issue around the catalog option to display all products.

Workaround option #1:

Override `limiter.phtml` in your theme:

`app/design/frontend/Your/Theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list/toolbar/limiter.phtml`

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
?>
<?php
/**
 * Product list toolbar
 *
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar $block
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Locale\LocaleFormatter $localeFormatter
 */
?>
<div class="field limiter">
    <label class="label" for="limiter">
        <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Show')) ?></span>
    </label>
    <div class="control">
        <select id="limiter" data-role="limiter" class="limiter-options">
            <?php foreach ($block->getAvailableLimit() as $_key => $_limit):?>
                <option value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_key) ?>"
                    <?php if ($block->isLimitCurrent($_key)):?>
                        selected="selected"
                    <?php endif ?>>
                    <?= $block->escapeHtml($_limit) ?>
                </option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
    </div>
    <span class="limiter-text"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('per page')) ?></span>
</div>
```

After doing so be sure to run: `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`

Workaround option #2:

Turn off `Allow All Products per Page` by going to `Stores > Settings > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog`

Set `Allow All Products per Page` to No

[image]

After doing so be sure to run:

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/35900#issuecomment-1210181110

Answer (score 0):

This should fix the issue: https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/bb55549cd3016987663272e7ffe3f452c8d6e40d

You can create a patch for it.

`vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list/toolbar/limiter.phtml`

```
            <?php if ($block->isLimitCurrent($_key)):?>
                selected="selected"
            <?php endif ?>>
-           <?= $block->escapeHtml($localeFormatter->formatNumber((int) $_limit)) ?>
+           <?= $block->escapeHtml(
+               is_numeric($_limit) ? $localeFormatter->formatNumber((int) $_limit) : $_limit
+           ) ?>
        </option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```